# Finding percentile for each data point in a numpy array

Tags: numpy, percentile

I have the following line of code:

```
threshold_value = numpy.percentile(a, q)
```

where `a` is my data and `q` is set at 95 let us say.

And let us say that if I changed `q` to be 90, I would get a different threshold value.

Well for each data point in `a`, I would like to calculate what value of q would yield `threshold_value` equal to a.  So what I am interested in is perhaps a data point in `a` is below the threshold_value, but I want a percentile value to see exactly where is it at.  When I have a test dataset, I compare each value to the threshold value to see if it exceeds it or not.  So I don't want to give a q value, I want to be told what the q value is for a data point.

So I want function maybe `a_percentile = function(a)` where a_percentile is a transformation of the original data value to the percentile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scipy.stats.percentileofscore https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore
a = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
[percentileofscore(a, i, kind='strict') for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
```

Comment: Yes I am sure that is the answer to the question I asked.  Thanks for that.  List comprehension to apply `percentileofscore` over each element in `a`.  So I give you the accepted answer.  However, on seeing the results, I guess I am really looking for something else so I will need to regather my thoughts.

Comment: There are different options within ```percentileofscore```. Looking at your question again, I think you actually want ```kind='strict'```. I've updated the answer.